# If or switch? Which of these is a cleaner, more conventional code?

Tags: c#, if-statement, switch-statement

I learned, that if you can use switch cases, you should use them, because they are better in performance. Which one of the following code snippets would be more conventional? And how many cases that behave exactly the same are still ok for switch statements and when should you start using if statements?

```
        Console.Write("Insert a card value: ");
        int value = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        string symbol = "";
        switch(value)
        {
            case 1:
            case 2:
            case 3:
            case 4:
            case 5:
            case 6:
            case 7:
            case 9:
            case 10:
                symbol = Convert.ToString(value);
                break;
            case 11:
                symbol = "J";
                break;
            case 12:
                symbol = "Q";
                break;
            case 13:
                symbol = "K";
                break;
            case 14:
                symbol = "A";
                break;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("The " + symbol + " has a value of " + value);
```

Or maybe this one?

```
    Console.Write("Insert a card value: ");
    int value = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    string symbol = "";
    if (value <= 10)
        symbol = Convert.ToString(value);
    else if (value == 11)
        symbol = "J";
    else if (value == 12)
        symbol = "Q";
    else if (value == 13)
        symbol = "K";
    else if (value == 14)
        symbol = "A";
    Console.WriteLine("The " + symbol + " has a value of " + value);
```

Comment: The if statement is far far easier to read than the switch. There is no need to use a switch here. The performance benefits are extremely negligible and should not really be worried about in this case. Edit: from looking it up switches are only better if you have a large number of if statements and in that case you probably have a better way of doing it.

Comment: In general, this will be a matter of personal opinion, and depend from case to case. In your particular case (and generally in most cases), I would say an If-else structure is more clean (readable). I'm pretty sure the difference in performance, if any at all, are quite negligible, so I would only consider readability when deciding this.

Comment: Its what you prefer to use. generally most people would simply do the if statement for this small amount of code. Speed in this case is not a factor. I personally find the switch statement easier to skim over quickly. but its at the expense of extra lines of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from C#9, there is a new pattern matching which makes the switch very well readable:

```
string symbol = value switch
{
     >=1 and <=10 => Convert.ToString(value),
     11 => "J",
     12 => "Q",
     13 => "K",
     14 => "A",
     _ => ""
};
```

Online demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/tovo7d